# How to bound a function?

Tags: calculus

For $x > 0, 0 < t < 2$, is there a function $g(t)$ such that $$f(x) = x^t\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{x}+1\right) \leq g(t)\quad \forall x?$$

For $t \leq 1$,  a function plot shows that $f$ is bounded above, so $g(t)$ can be given by a constant. But for $t = 1.5$, it seems $f$ is not bounded by a constant as an increasing function. Can $f$ be bounded by a function of $t$ instead?

Comment: Do you mean a function of only $t$?. As you said f is not bounded above and so as t is a constant any function $g(t)$ will also be a constant and so couldn't bound $f$ above.

Comment: Yes, a function of only $t$. But, I am not sure in fact if $f(x, t)$ can be bounded by $g(t)$ above.

Comment: In that case $f$ can't be bounded. You are right that $f$ cannot be bounded by a constant and so as $t$ is a constant, any function $g(t)$ will be a constant and so can't bound $f$.

Comment: I am seeking an answer of a formal proof or counter-proof.